# Countdown for badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

Is there any possibility to see the progress of badge achievement?

I mean, let's say that it is needed X action to get a badge, and I fulfilled (X - Y), so, I would like to see something like this near the badge list:

> [ Badge X ] : 58% completed (12 actions to finish)

Can we see this detail somewhere? If not yet, can be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

The review-related badges are now tracked with the green bar in the review page. You can mouse over that bar to get more info. They should appear in all the review categories except the old (legacy) review lists accessible with the link at the bottom of the [review](https://askubuntu.com/review) page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the badge progress tracking functionality you're looking for is provided by [this third-party stack app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges).

(That can only track progress based on accessible information, though, and some information--like who has voted for what posts--is not accessible.)